# How do I use TelephonyManager with nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to access android native api class method like this:

```
android.telephony.TelephonyManager.someMethod()
```

I am getting 'Cannot read property someMethod'. 
Do I need to add a require statement or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To correctly use the android `TelephonyManager` you should get a reference to an instance via the `Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)` call. So in NativeScript that would be something similar to the following:

`var telephonyMgr = android.content.Context().getSystemService(TELEPHONY_MANAGER);`

that would give you your reference to then call the methods available from the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

In NativeScript you also have access to the *"application"* module that you can require in your code `var app = require("application");` and to get a valid context (for android) it is `app.android.currentContext`

Comment: the above code does not work for incoming calls. It does not capture states of an incoming call but for an outgoing call it does. Any idea?

Comment: Wow, it does work. You only need `android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` permission.